# Where Can I Find Emoticons Stored in Sametime 8.5.2 and SameTime 7?

Tags: emoticons, lotus-sametime

Where on the HDD can I find default Sametime emoticons Stored?.

Comment: What operating system?  Sametime Connect works on all the big ones.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Verbatim from [Sametime support](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/stwiki.nsf/dx/Using_and_managing_Sametime_emoticons).

> File location
>
> The palette data and image files are stored on your local drive; the
>   location of the stored files varies by Sametime client type (Connect
>   or embedded) and version.  The relevant subdirectory, which will be a
>   subdirectory of the main program directory, is
>   plugins\com.ibm.collaboration.realtime.palettes.
>       To identify the full path location for emoticons when using a Sametime Connect or Notes embedded client, do the following:

```
Open a chat window with yourself
Insert an emoticon, and click Send or press enter
Right-click the emoticon, then select "Copy Image Location"
Paste the location into a text editor, like Notepad.  You now have the location for your client's palette files.
```

Answer (score 1):

Sametime 8.5.2 on Win 7:

`C:\Users\<USER>\AppData\Roaming\Lotus\Sametime\.metadata\.plugins\com.ibm.collaboration.realtime.palettes`